# Calcular diferença entre datas em dias no R

Tags: datetime, r

Como faço para calcular a diferença entre datas e ter o resultado em dias?

Eu tenho uma coluna na minha tabela chamada de entrada com dados parecidos com os exibidos abaixo:

Entrada

> 2017-01-27
>   2017-06-01
>   2017-10-05
>   2017-09-27
>   2017-08-31
>   2017-04-02
>   2017-03-30
>   2017-07-01
>   2017-07-27
>   2017-10-24
>   2017-02-23
>   2017-02-10
>   2017-05-26
>   ...

Eu tentei calcular a diferença pela data específica do dia 2018-01-01 (data padrão para todo o cálculo) utilizando a função:

```
entrada["atualização"] <- difftime((entrada), 2018-01-01, units = c("days"))
```

E tive como resposta

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda de como resolver esse problema ou outra maneira para calcular a diferença entre essas datas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, não sei bem quais são os nomes dos seus dados, vou chamar à data frame `time1` e à sua coluna `entrada`. Se isto não estiver certo diga que é só mudar os nomes, o código continua a correr bem.

Em segundo lugar, veja o que escreveu na instrução `difftime`:

```
difftime((entrada), 2018-01-01, units = c("days"))
```

Este `2018-01-01` ***não é uma data*** é uma subtração de três números! Tente executar isto na linha de comando e veja o que dá. Além disso, não são necessários os parentesis em `(entrada)` nem a função `c()` em `c("days")`. Não é que dê erro, simplesmente não é preciso(*).

Agora o código. Para aplicar o `difftime` ambas as datas têm de ser ou herdar de classe `Date` ou `POSIXt` (por exemplo `POSIXct` ou `POSIXlt`). Portanto usamos a função `as.Date` na coluna inteira e na data base `2018-01-01`.

```
time1$entrada <- as.Date(time1$entrada)

time1[["atualização"]] <- difftime(time1$entrada, as.Date("2018-01-01"), units = "days")

time1
#      entrada atualização
#1  2017-01-27   -339 days
#2  2017-06-01   -214 days
#3  2017-10-05    -88 days
#4  2017-09-27    -96 days
#5  2017-08-31   -123 days
#6  2017-04-02   -274 days
#7  2017-03-30   -277 days
#8  2017-07-01   -184 days
#9  2017-07-27   -158 days
#10 2017-10-24    -69 days
#11 2017-02-23   -312 days
#12 2017-02-10   -325 days
#13 2017-05-26   -220 days
```

**DADOS**

```
dput(time1)
structure(list(entrada = c("2017-01-27", "2017-06-01", "2017-10-05", 
"2017-09-27", "2017-08-31", "2017-04-02", "2017-03-30", "2017-07-01", 
"2017-07-27", "2017-10-24", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-10", "2017-05-26"
)), .Names = "entrada", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

(*) A função `c()` será necessária para criar vetores com mais que um elemento, `c("days")` só tem um elemento. Por exemplo, `c("a", "b")` já tem mais que um elemento.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas existe a possibilidade de exibir o resultado sem o sinal de - na frente dos dias? Ou existe algum comando que eu possa utilizar para tirar o sinal?

Comment: @dflagher Lá haver há, mas o sinal tem significado. Para o valor absoluto da diferença, é só fazer `abs(difftime(etc))`.